# SQL COUNT on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the code i got so far

```
SELECT users_ID,Problem_ID 
FROM 'submission'
WHERE Status = "AC" 
GROUP BY users_ID,Problem_ID
```

I am getting these results

```
+----------+------------+
| Users_ID | Problem_ID |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          1 |
|        1 |          2 |
|        1 |          3 |
|        2 |          1 |
|        2 |          3 |
+----------+------------+
```

### I only want to get

```
+----------+------------+
| Users_ID | Problem_ID |
+----------+------------+
|        1 |          3 | --  so because there are 3 results for user_ID 1
|        2 |          2 | -- and there are 2 results for user_ID 2
+----------+------------+
```

So the `Problem_ID` is how many rows I am getting from my query for each user.
But how do I accomplish this?

### Edit:

I forgot mention that the table contains duplicates of the same problem for example.
I got a `Problem` with the `ID` of `1` and then in the database there could be two rows with the same user and with status as `"AC"` but I want to only get one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT users_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Problem_ID)
FROM `submission`
WHERE Status = 'AC' 
GROUP BY users_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT users_ID, count(Problem_ID) as `problem_count`
 FROM `submission`
 WHERE Status = 'AC' 
 GROUP BY users_ID;
```

Comment: But i don't want to count the duplicates of "AC" on a problem so the user dosen't get more points if he has gotten "AC" often on the same problem.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT user_id and problem_id INTO a temporary table and then execute the above query on the temp table.

Comment: You guided me to the right answer, thank you!
SELECT DISTINCT users_ID,COUNT(DISTINCT Problem_ID) 
    FROM submission 
    WHERE Status = "AC" 
    GROUP BY users_ID

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
    s.users_ID
    ,count(s.Problem_ID)+CASE WHEN IFNULL(userDupli.nbrUserAC, 0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as `problem_count`
FROM 
    `submission` s
    left join (SELECT 
                   users_ID
                   ,count(*) as nbrUserAC 
               FROM `submission` 
               WHERE Status = 'AC' 
               GROUP BY users_ID) userDupli
        on userDupli.users_ID = s.users_ID
WHERE 
    Status <> 'AC' 
GROUP BY 
    users_ID
    ,userDupli.nbrUserAC
```